# Going extensionless with redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My site has more than 500 dynamic pages and i have make all static (same) pages and redirect old url or new url by using the following rule in htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=2&gas=nitrogen$
RewriteRule ^purity\.php$ http://Example.com/gases/nitrogen.php? [R=301,L]
```

and by using this code for all my pages are now static url's

and now i want to make it http://www.Example.com/gases/nitrogen (without extension) and for this i have uploaded the rule which is :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^\ ]+)\.php\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301]
```

This code is actually redirecting my php page to non php page but with 404 error.

Im unable to figure out the problem in this.

Pls help!!

Comment: try `Options +MultiView`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with what you are trying to do. You have to understand how rewrites work. You're making your webserver serve up a different page that doesn't exist. So by sending an ugly url to a better SEO'd one, you're saying ok server give me this page instead. If the page itself doesn't exist, then the server spits up a 404 error. Your rewrite should be from the page you want them to go to redirects to your old page name without the [R] parameter so your server knows, don't give this page, give that other page, and don't let them know it's being done by displaying that other url, that's what removing the [R] does. Then to prevent the endless redirect loop, don't redirect the ugly page name to the new one. Instead, simply display the redirected url instead of the ugly one with all those ugly looking parameters. however since you've probably already been indexed and search engines know about the ugly pages, I would recommend not only not linking to those pages anymore and use the new page names on all your pages for things like navigation, and referencing other pages, but I would add the canonical meta tag on your pages telling Google and other search engines what your preferred url is. If you had started out without any search engines knowing your url structure with all those parameters you could have skipped using the canonical meta tag as the search engines wouldn't know your pages by those names if you always used a rewrite.